# iframe with float disappearing in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, iframe

I have a site that uses an iframe to load an audio player from Archive.org. The site has been working fine for three years. However, when I upgraded Chrome yesterday to version 60, the iframes show up for an instant and then disappear. The site still works fine in other browsers.

For instance, the page http://gratefuldeadoftheday.com/02-13-1970 has the following iframe:

```
<iframe class="archive-l" frameborder="0" height="400" 
src="https://archive.org/embed/gd1970-02-13.sbd.miller.fix-
97613.97639.sbeok.flac16&amp;playlist=1" width="300"></iframe>
```

The archive-l class includes a float: left. If I remove the float: left, the iframe renders in Chrome. And, if I remove the float, wrap the iframe in a div, and float the div, the iframe renders. You can see that I have done that here: http://gratefuldeadoftheday.com/08-26-1971

Obviously, I can wrap the iframes on all 2000+ pages in a div and get it to work, but I would still like to understand why this problem is occurring.

Comment: The only problem I see with Chrome 60 is the width of the iframe...

Comment: @Alessio Why is the width a problem?

Comment: I see the content is cut

Comment: @Alessio I see what you are saying on the 02-13-1970 page. But that is not causing the issue. As you can see, iframes in other pages - such as http://gratefuldeadoftheday.com/08-20-1983 - where the content is not cut off are still disappearing.

Comment: I see, have you tried to set also a width to the iframe? <iframe width="300" ... >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that floated iframes disappearing after loading was a known issue in Chrome version 60. The issue has been fixed in version 61.
[You can see more about this here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/_vKs56fkPb8) and [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/chrome/lXPOJcoGufk/ngPruQrICAAJ).

Answer (score 1):

I find out a dirty workaround: you should trigger a width change / resize on iframe.

Try:

```
jQuery('.field__item iframe').css('width','auto');
```

Comment: Please approve the answer and upvote it if it was helpful ;) Thanks

Comment: I appreciate the workaround. But you are not answering my question about what is causing the issue.

Comment: For anyone who comes across this, the above JQuery workaround only seems to make the iframe visible until a user clicks on something in the iframe. After clicking on the iframe, the content again disappears.

Comment: @kosher but that workaround does not work on click, you should run it once the iframe has finished loading. For example if I run it in console once the page is fully loaded, the iframe remains always visibile. Maybe you are running it before the page is fully loaded?